# I'm using a stream provider along with a Navigator.push(), how to detect changes to stream in new route

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-contentprovider

I'm currently using a StreamProvider to read a list 'ThreadsList' from firebase. This list is passed down the widget tree through a

```
onTap: () {
 Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) =>
  ThreadPage(thread: thread, shadowUID: shadowUID, poll: poll))
 );
},
```

When the stream provider recieves new data the 'thread: thread' updates however in the new route that is being pushed, 'Thread Page' 'the value of thread doesn't change.

How can I make the new route detect changes in the thread object from where I pushed the ThreadPage.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the only solution is to listen to the stream on your next route.

Comment: I thought so too, but I would have to have two stream providers, wouldn't this double the number of reads

Comment: you could stop listening on your first listener which would make it read only once. I don't think this is the most effective solution though.

Comment: Any ideas, the only solution I could think off is displaying the information on the same page however there isn't enough space for me to do so, and I would much rather prefer a separate page.

Comment: that's my only idea or you can create a separate listener and listen to it and place the values in a custom class or list or whatever.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your input will try implementing something similar.

Comment: Could you please share the complete code to see the stream provider getting data?

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this question I posted right after. It refers to how I implemented the stream provider. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270476/streamprovider-works-correctly-however-on-stream-update-child-widgets-dont-reb

Comment: After checking your code from the other post, I understand that you are not able to detect the changes in the stream in a new route because the threadlist is not been updated inside the widget as you mentioned in the other post. So could you please share the whole code in this post and explain the workflow of the code, I mean, explain when you create provider, which widget is been called first , onTap is called when etc ?

Comment: Hi, I did a bit more research and the only solution was the use a stream provider or use a static list. The navigaton.push function is not refreshed when set state is called, and so there is no way to update the contents of the new widget, without reopening it. Thanks for your help though.